# How to get the time a user spends on a whole journey from session start to session end on AppInsights

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-application-insights

We need to monitor the time a user needs to complete a complete journey on our site using `AppInsights` from session start to session end.

We are logging everything on `AppInsights` but we are pretty new to the tool so we are not sure about how to get this information. Using `Funnels` or `User Flows` we can see the navigation of the user but there the time it took to the user to do it is not available.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is correlation. You can find a write up of the built in features [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation). You can also issue your own correlation Id (new Guid) and pass that around with you code to be 100% explicit and cater for scenarios where a user may be "absent" from the app for a long period (e.g. walks away from his browser for a coffee and comes back 30 minutes later, possibly after your app service restarts for some reason). You will still need to calculate the time each piece of the journey took, and would also need to instrument the UI if you want to track activity/inactivity in user interaction.

Comment: Hi, looks interesting but maybe it's more than what we are looking for, for us is enough to know the time it took to go from page x to page y. Is there a simple way to get that?

Comment: Add a guid correlation id to your logging, also add the page id / name. Log the start of a request and the end of it. Then you can  search your logs and build up a picture.